# Prevent on screen keyboard from dismissing when using swipe gestures with iOS Voiceover

Tags: ios, reactjs, web, accessibility, voiceover

I have a react web app with a textfield and a send button.
While using voiceover with iOS Safari browser, focusing on the textfield opens up the on screen keyboard. However, swiping right moves the focus to the send button and the on screen keyboard disappears.

This is an a11y problem. How can I keep the keyboard focused until it is explicitly dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attempt to override the default iOS Voiceover behavior.  When you swipe to an input field, you have to **double tap** to get the keyboard to display (iOS 15.5).  It doesn't display automatically like you're describing it.  It'd be nice if Apple moved the Voiceover focus **into** the keyboard, but it doesn't.  Since the focus is still on the input field, swiping right will move the focus to the 'send' button.  This is an Apple decision that you shouldn't try to code around.